# Windows, command line and proxy

Tags: windows, networking, https

Our corporate network has a nice proxy screening all internet activity. Requests without AD credentials are refused (unless exceptions are set up). This is a bit problematic as we can access content from the browser, but not from the command line.

For powershell, this works:

```
$wc = new Net.WebClient()
$wc.Proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
$wc.DownloadString('http://www.google.com')
```

But of course, tools that try to access the internet, or things like Vagrant up can't do this. Any ideas on what we can do to attach our credentials to any and all network requests (specially those from the command line)?

I should add that http and https are both blocked by the proxy when credentials aren't supplied.

Comment: you should better ask in serverfault I think

Comment: Thanks...I'll do that. Is there a way to "move" the question, or should I create a new one?

Comment: admins might have that power ... me not ;)

Comment: A question can be migrated by 5 migration votes or a moderator. But only moderators can migrate from here to Server Fault.